# Can you tell me what is the problem in this code:

Tags: php, mysql

Can you tell me what the problem in this code is:

```
<?php
include('config.php');
$name=$_POST['name'];
$sms=$_POST['sms'];
$os=$_POST['os'];
$nop=$_POST['nop'];
$dl=$_POST['dl'];
$tapb=$_POST['tapb'];
$date=$_POST['date'];
$calls=$_POST['calls'];
$ft=$_POST['ft'];
$train=$_POST['train'];
$tds=$_POST['tds'];
$ws=$_POST['ws'];
$airl=$_POST['airl'];
$comm=$_POST['comm'];
$tid=$_POST['tid'];
$ial=$_POST['ial'];
$tamt=$_POST['tamt'];
$btype=$_POST['btype'];
$from=$_POST['from'];
$cuspay=$_POST['cuspay'];
$comment=$_POST['comment'];
$to=$_POST['to'];
$pays=$_POST['pays'];
$payee=$_POST['payee'];
$jdate=$_POST['jdate'];
$payment=$_POST['payment'];
$rv=$_POST['rv'];
$rvia=$_POST['rvia'];
$redate=$_POST['redate'];
$mpay=$_POST['mpay'];
$total=$_POST['total'];
$totalr=$_POST['totalr'];

$result=mysql_query ("INSERT INTO booking (name, sms, out_standing, no_of_pax, delivery, tkt_amt_payed_by, booked_date, calls, flight_time, flight_train, tds, wish_sms, air_lines, commiss, transation_id, indian_airline, tkt_amt, booking_type, from, customer_payment, comment, to, payment_status, payee, journy_date, payment_date, return_date, mode_of_payment, return_via1, return_via2, total, total_received)
VALUES ('$name', '$sms', '$os','$nop','$dl','$tapb','$date','$calls','$train','$ft','$train','$tds','$ws','$airl','$comm','$tid','$ial','$tamt','$btype','$from','$cuspay','$comment','$to','$pays','$payee','$jdate','$payment','$redate','$mpay','$rv','$rvia','$total','$totalr')") or die("Query failed : " . mysql_error());
header('Location: booking.php');  
mysql_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: Is that you're not sanitizing you query. Btw, what's the error?

Comment: What exactly is the error you are getting?

Comment: Ouch that's ugly. One, we need to know the error you are getting. Two, please give us a reason why you are taking posted values and injecting them right into a query!!!

Comment: Dude, use foreach($_POST as $key => $value) { $$key = $value }

Comment: are you connecting/selecting the db? what errors are you getting? this is vulnerable to sql injection

Comment: besides being extremely ugly?

Comment: @FinalForm: Blindly stuffing everything from $_POST into a same-named variable like that can lead to unanticipated variables being vulnerable to tampering.  That's the very reason why register_globals has been deprecated.  Better would be something like `foreach (array('name', 'sms', 'os',....) as $key) $$key = $_POST[$key];`.  That way some jerk can't mess around with variables you didn't intend for them to.

Comment: @cHao I don't agree with your decision to stick everything into its own independent variable. This does not look optimum, especially for scenarios where one needs to avoid namespace collision. Additionally, it is not "blindly" stuffing variables into an array if one takes the time to write code to check. If your code base is short / small, then I can imagine your method might be acceptable.

Comment: @FinalForm: Wasn't my decision.  The OP was doing it already.  And you'd suggested a method of doing the same thing.  While it is much shorter, it also has the side effect of importing everything from $_POST into the global namespace, whether it was in the list or not.  If we're not careful, someone could post "is_admin=1" or something and the code would trust it because we're expecting register_globals to be off.  (This can be more of a problem in larger projects than smaller ones, as there's more chance of namespace collisions.)  I simply provided a way to prevent that.

Comment: @cHao Um, your methodology is the global name space. :-/ $$variable IS THE GLOBAL SPACE. I think you have your terminologies confused. http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php . I suggested a route for him to put it behind a name space and segment it off from the global space to some degree. Additionally, is_admin = 1 is a problem in his code for not checking. It does not detract from the efficiency of a 2 liner vs his 30+ lines.

Comment: @FinalForm: I don't see where you made that suggestion.  In fact, the only reason i said anything was that your suggestion imported everything from $_POST, rather than just the variables that were intended.  Other than that, it does the exact same thing as mine does.  :P  Checking internal variables after they've already been imported (read: tampered with by the client) is a pain.  Better to avoid it altogether than try to code around it, IMO.

Comment: @cHao Um, you didn't counter my argument guy. You're basically redressing the same thing again. You're saying injection of values from a post is some how magically mitigated by doing dollar dollar. :-/

Comment: @FinalForm: Did you read your code?  If that were my argument, we'd both be wrong.  No, I'm saying that unintended injection is made all-but-impossible by having a list of names of stuff to copy, and only copying those rather than everything.

Answer (score 2):

I actually spent the time looking through the query... the line `VALUES ('$name', '$sms', '$os','$nop','$dl','$tapb','$date','$calls','$train','$ft','$train',` you have `$train` twice.  My guess is the first is a typo and you should remove it.  The number of columns and values do not match up.

Also as others have said, there is much more wrong here...

Answer (score 0):

a lot of errors

- you are not sanitizing you query parameters (as pointed by @Damien)
- you are using the dates direct from the `$_POST` without checking the date format

I am just lazy to keep going...

Comment: re: the `mysql_close` after `die`: When the script dies, the connection will be closed by PHP (as part of the cleanup stuff), and the script's `mysql_close` will never run.  It's not an issue.  Agreed on the rest, though.

Comment: hmmm, that's true... the documentation says it pretty clear that `using mysql_close() isn't usually necessary,`. Tks!

Answer (score 0):

your values dont match up with your fields. you got 32 fields but 33 values

you forgot the field between *flight_train* and  *tds* in your fields definition i suspect

and there is much more wrong with this code, please refer to the comments for that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a, slightly, better code:

```
<?php
include 'config.php';

$keys = array('name', 'sms', 'os', ...); // Put in the rest of the values yourself

$values = array();

foreach($keys as $key) {
    if(!isset($_POST[$key])) {
        // handle missing input, do validation etc
    }
    else
        $values[] = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$key]) . "'";
}

$query = sprintf("INSERT INTO booking (%s) VALUES (%s)", implode($keys, ', '), implode($values ', '));

$result = mysql_query($query);
mysql_close($con);

if(!$result)
    die(mysql_error());
else
    header('Location: booking.php');  
?>
```